# How to get all users from MySql database and put into arraylist

Tags: java, mysql, database, arraylist, jdbc

I am creating a java application which will allow users to register, login and update their details. The data is stored in a MySQL database which is already successfully connected to my application.

I would like to be able to get all data of a user, which will be used to create a user object and make a array list of all users, which will be type "user".

What I would like to know is if ID be a good property to have for a "user" object as I have their names and usernames(which is unique to the users).

When the user log in to their account the user list should have all users in the arraylist and be positioned to the logged in user. Which I do not know how to do.

I have uploaded my current code so far:

```
public class UserAccountList {

private static UserAccountList instance;
private ArrayList<user> userList;
user newUser = null;
int currentUser;

protected UserAccountList() throws IOException {
    this.userList = new ArrayList<>();
    readDatabase();   
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    ArrayList<user> userList1 = new UserAccountList().getUserList();
    for(int i=0;i<userList1.size();i++){
        System.out.println(userList1.get(i).getUsername());
    }
}
public ArrayList getUserList() throws IOException {
    return this.userList;

}

public static UserAccountList getInstance() throws IOException {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new UserAccountList();
    }
    return instance;
}



private void readDatabase() throws IOException {
     PreparedStatement ps;
     ResultSet rs;

     String query = "SELECT * FROM `user`" ;

     try{
    ps = MyConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);


    rs = ps.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next() != false){

        String uname = rs.getString("username");
        String pass = rs.getString("password");
        String fname = rs.getString("firstname");
        String lname = rs.getString("lastname");
        String email = rs.getString("email");
        String uni = rs.getString("university");
        String course = rs.getString("course");

        user newUser = new user(fname, lname, uname, pass, email, uni, course);
        addUser(newUser);
    }

   }

    catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FXMLRegistrationController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}


public void addUser(user newUser){
    userList.add(newUser);
    return;
}
}
```

Comment: What is the output of your current code? Please remove single quote for table name 
  String query = "SELECT * FROM user" ;

Comment: The program does not give out any errors, I am able to login and register users just fine. Only problem is that it only makes changes to the user in the first position of the array because I dont know how to get the position of the user that is currently logged in.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to try

```
while(rs.next()){

    String uname = rs.getString(1);
    String pass = rs.getString(2);
    String fname = rs.getString(3);
    String lname = rs.getString(4); //Presuming they are in this order
    String email = rs.getString(5);
    String uni = rs.getString(6);
    String course = rs.getString(7);

    user newUser = new user(fname, lname, uname, pass, email, uni, course);
    addUser(newUser);
}
```

From my point of view, it's always a good idea to have ID, but I don't think it's necessary in your case. As for positioning the User, I presume it's the `currentUser` variable. When you pass the verification and get the user that logged in. Use `userList.indexOf(loggedInUser)`

Comment: Thanks for getting back! I have made change to the while statement to get the data but what I don't understand is how do I know which user is logged in? My idea was to create a user object of who is logged in the log in controller class and use that object in the changeProfile class but the object is not global and only in scope of the logIn class.

Comment: So first off how to get the user, in your log in controller class, where you check if the user exists, and whether the credentials are correct. To do that, you would have to go through the user list, and once the credentials match, return the user.  Next stop is the make sure you can always access that user variable. You can do that multiple ways, what is best, depends on your program architecture.
For exaple, you can set it as a variable in your MainFrame that you always have access to.

Comment: Or using your `UserAccountList class` when you check for the user, return the index of the user in the list. And that way you can always access it with `userList.get(index)`

Comment: Eitherway suits you best. I think the solution to your problem is only getting the user. So when you are going to through the list to check credentials. When the username and password match, just `return user`. I would use a for each loop for that.

Comment: THANK YOU! I got it working and its now only changing data to user that is currently logged in!

Comment: @pajo29: userList.indexOf(loggedInUser) will work properly only if the `equals` and `hashCode` methods implemented properly in the `user` class.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply iterate over your list of `user` called `userList` and compare every user object's username property with the username of current logged in user:

```
user currentLoggedInUser = null;
String username = "username of current logged in user";// you have this, right?
for(user u: userList){
    if(username.equals()){
        currentLoggedInUser = u;
        break;
    }
}
```

**BUT**

If I were you I would store the `user` objects in a `HashMap<String,user>` instead of a `ArrayList<user>`:

```
public class UserAccountList {
    //private ArrayList<user> userList;
    Map<String,user> users = new HashMap<String,user>(); // instead of above userList
    ...

    public void addUser(user newUser){
        users.put(newUser.getUsername, newUser);// key is username, value is the user object
    }
}
```

So when a user is logged in and you try to change some of it's properties, you can obtain it's object from the `users` Map collection simply without iterating over the whole list:

```
String username = "username of current logged in user";
user loggedInUser = users.get(username);
```

and now you have the corresponding user object.

Hope this would be helpful.